# merge files like in an archive

Tags: c#, file, encryption, storing-data

I have a lot of files that i want to encrypt and then store in one big file like an archive. Then i want to be able to read the files from the "archive". I know how to encrypt/decrypt the files but i don't know how to store them in one file. And i want to know what is the best method to be able to add/read/delete files fast from this "archive". This is the encryption that i use: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26085/File-Encryption-and-Decryption-in-C

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sounds like you want us to design the entire application for you. If you don't have a design or idea, why not use a standard API like Bobson proposes?

Answer (score 3):

Easy answer: Use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.Password= "123456!";
    zip.AddFile("ReadMe.txt");
    zip.AddFile("7440-N49th.png");
    zip.AddFile("2005_Annual_Report.pdf");        
    zip.Save("Backup.zip");
}
```

You don't need to worry about encrypting it yourself this way.  Although you could still encrypt each file yourself and then zip them together.